# How do i combine two XML objects in node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml, node.js

This is the first XML which is stored in an object named 'doc'.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
    <playtext lang="EN" speed="2" quality="best">
       This is response
    </playtext>
</response>
```

This is the second XML which is stored in an object named 'root'.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<collectdtmf 1="1" t="#" o="30">
    <playtext speed="2" lang="EN" quality="best">
        Press 1, for sales
    </playtext>
    <playtext speed="2" lang="EN" quality="best">
        Press 2, to know more about company
    </playtext>
</collectdtmf>
```

My aim is to combine these XML into one and get the result as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
    <playtext lang="EN" speed="2" quality="best">
       This is response
    </playtext>
    <collectdtmf 1="1" t="#" o="30">
        <playtext speed="2" lang="EN" quality="best">
            Press 1, for sales
        </playtext>
        <playtext speed="2" lang="EN" quality="best">
            Press 2, to know more about company
        </playtext>
      </collectdtmf>
 </response>
```

i am using the npm 'xmlbuilder' to create this XML object;
How can i do this using node.js?

Comment: What did you try? Please show some attempts.

Comment: i saw some code used in php like  
           $collect_dtmf = $this->doc->importNode($cd->getRoot(), true);
And i want exactly the same result used in the above code(php) . Searched a lot...but couldn't find anything.